# Microsoft translator error

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-translator

I am trying to use microsoft translator and each time I am trying to create `LanguageServiceClient` I get an error.

```
try
{
    // Add the http header
    string headerValue = GetAccessToken();
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Method = "POST";
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", headerValue);

    TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient client = new TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient();
    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
        result = client.Detect("", textToTranslate);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    result = "Error: " + ex.Message;
}
```

The error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'TranslatorService.LanguageService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you already tried checking _"This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."_?

Comment: yeah thanks i discovered the error i was putting the service configuration in class library where i do translation logic 
i tried to add it to website configuration file "web.config" and its working now Thanks @StevenJeuris

Comment: You are always allowed to answer your own question, this way it doesn't stay 'open'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the error.

I was putting the service configuration in a class library where I do the translation logic. I tried to add it to the website configuration file "web.config" instead, and it's working now.