# trouble with service reference

Tags: service, reference

I added a service reference that points to http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/soap.svc in my project. After adding the reference an app.config file was created.

When I run the project everything works. After creating a setup file with Advanced Installer (program for authoring Windows Installer setup packages) I get the following error message when I run the installed program.

"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract TranslatorService.LanguageService in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not generated by the setup package created with Advanced Installer, it seems to be .NET specific. Here is another similar thread: [Microsoft translator error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453520/microsoft-translator-error)

Comment: Ok, but when I publish the project with visual studio into a setup file, it works. It seems that the app.config file is not properly linked into the setup file made by advanced installer.

Comment: Can you see the app.config file in Files and Folders page, in the folders where your resources are located? Also, note that Advanced Installer has a built-in editor for XML files, so make sure you didn't accidentally imported and edited the file.

Comment: Hei! 

Do you mean in the \bin\debug folder or do you mean in the top level project folder? I copied them in both folders and run advanced installer, but the problem remains. What a headache.

Comment: I can't know the paths where your service is waiting for the config file to be present. If you give me a download link for the MSI created with VS and the project file created with Advanced Installer I could take a look over them and see the differences.

Also, another option is to create a new project in Advanced Installer by importing the MSI created by VS (File -> Import), which should allow importing the correct files and folders hierarchy.